# Looping nested comments in Laravel 8.x

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

In Laravel 8.x I am trying to create a blog comment system which allows you to reply to comments. If replying to a comment, the comment is assigned a `parent_id` which is the `id` of the comment they are replying to. Currently when I loop the comments with the replies, it will only output a reply 1 loop deep like the example below:

#### Current example of the problem:

User1: Random post 1..
> User2: This text is a response to User1 for post 1
User6: Random post 2..
User7: Random post 3..

#### What I am trying to achieve:

User1: Random post 1..
   > User2: This text is a response to User1 for post 1
     >> User3: This text is a response to User2 for post 1
        >>> User4: This text is a response to User3 for post 1
        >>> User5: This text is a response to User3 for post 1
User6: Random post 2..
User7: Random post 3..

#### My current code

Model:

```
class PostComment extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function replies()
    {
        return $this->hasMany($this, 'parent_id');
    }
}
```

Blade:

```
@foreach ($comments as $comment)

    <p> {{ $comment->user->name }} : {{ $comment->comment }} </p>

    @foreach ($comment->replies as $reply)

        <p> {{ $reply->user->name }} : {{ $reply->comment }} </p>

    @endforeach

@endforeach
```

Now if I add `@foreach ($comment->replies as $reply)` 4 times within the comment loop, it will display the replies.. but of course this isn't practical since there can be unlimited responses to a comment. I hope you can understand what I'm trying to get at, I'm awfully bad at explaining things.

Any help is really appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create two blade files

1. `comment-list.blade.php`
2. `child-comment-list.blade.php`

In **comment-list.blade.php**  file

```
@if(count((array)$comments))
    @foreach ($comments as $comment)
    
        <p> {{ $comment->user->name }} : {{ $comment->comment }} </p>
    
       @include('child-comment-list',['comments'=>$comment->replies])
    
        @endforeach
@endif
```

In **child-comment-list.blade.php**  file

```
@if(count((array)$comments))
 @foreach($comments as $comment)
 
  <p> {{ $comment->user->name }} : {{ $comment->comment }} </p>
   @if(count((array)$comment->replies))

            @include('child-comment-list',['comments'=>$comment->replies])

   @endif
 @endforeach
```

So in your current file

```
@include('comment-list',['comments'=>$comments]);
```

Comment: Wow.. incredible.. this has solved my issue! It worked perfectly, thank you so much!